# Can I modify Devise params from within an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, authentication, devise

I have this homework from a security class where I need to make an app using some sort of authentification system. So I decided to use ruby on rails and I got it all working with devise at the moment.

But for this home work I need an admin to be able to go into an admin page **within the app** and be able to modify some security options like :

- Being able to lock people after too many login attempts
- Complexity of user password

I can't seem to find anything on the internet for this...
Is this possible ? Should I use another method ?

Thank you,

Guillaume

Comment: [Devise has a lockable module](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Lockable) for the first issue. As for the second issue, I believe that you can use [devise_security_extension](https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension)

Comment: Hey thank you for devise_security_extension ! didn't know about that. But is there a way for a user to modify these parameters ? With a button or drop-down list from within the app